# Cycles of a multigraph with a property on the edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, weighted-graphs

Let $n$ be a positive integer. On a circle are arranged $n$ points $A_1$, $\ldots$, $A_n$. We put some arrows from $A_1$ to $A_2$, from $A_2$ to $A_3$, etc., from $A_n$ to $A_1$. On each arrow are written a string ($\textit{name}$ - so that we could distinguish all arrows from each other) and a number. How can we find all possibilities for $n$ arrows (output them with the arrows' names and numbers on them) with the following properties:

1. For some $1\leq i \leq n$ the first arrow is from $A_i$ to $A_{i+1}$, the second one from $A_{i+1}$ to $A_{i+2}$, etc., the $n$-th one from $A_{i-1}$ to $A_i$.
2. For any two consecutive arrows $R_1$ and $R_2$ (with the endpoint of $R_1$ being the startpoint of $R_2$), (number on $R_2$) - (number on $R_1$) = $1$.

(If too hard to be done efficiently for bigger $n$, a solution for $n\leq 4$ would be satisfactory.)

I can do it for $n=2$, but my approach does not generalize for larger $n$, since when $n=2$ its easy to just compare the arrows from $A_1$ to $A_2$ with the arrows from $A_2$ to $A_1$.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry I find your question very confusing.

Comment: @orlp What exactly is confusing?

Comment: What do you mean by "all possibilities for $n$ arrows"?   There are only $n$ possibilities that satisfy your first property; once you pick $i$, you just described exactly how to draw them.  Then you can just check if they satisfy the second property.  If you work through some examples I think you'll find that either all $n$ possibilities satisfy the second property or none do.  That seems too easy, so I suspect either I haven't understood the problem or some requirements are missing.  What's the context where you encountered this task?

Comment: @D.W. Ok but your idea is brute-forcing. What about a faster method like something similar to "Depth-First-Search" , say?

Comment: There are not $n$ possibilities, since from $A_i$ to $A_{i+1}$ there can be multiple arrows?

Comment: That wasn't clear.  Please [edit] the question to indicate that.  What's the context where you encountered this task?  Can you link to or credit the original source?